# Very strange Pandas behavior while using multi-indexing

Tags: python, pandas

I use the following code to create a Pandas DataFrame with multi-index and update some values.

```py
indices = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables=[['X','Y','Z'],['h1','h2','h3']],names=['idx1','idx2'])
df = pd.DataFrame(0.0,index=indices,columns=['A'])

df.loc['X','A']['h1'] = 1.1
df.loc['Y','A']['h1'] = 2.2
df.loc['Z','A']['h1'] = 3.3

print(df)
```

This code generates the following output, as expected:

```py
             A
idx1 idx2
X    h1    1.1
     h2    0.0
     h3    0.0
Y    h1    2.2
     h2    0.0
     h3    0.0
Z    h1    3.3
     h2    0.0
     h3    0.0
```

But when I use the following code (note the 'Y' in the first index is moved at the end), the output is wrong:

```
import pandas as pd
indices = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables=[['X','Z','Y'],['h1','h2','h3']],names=['idx1','idx2'])
df = pd.DataFrame(0.0,index=indices,columns=['A'])

df.loc['X','A']['h1'] = 1.1
df.loc['Y','A']['h1'] = 2.2
df.loc['Z','A']['h1'] = 3.3

print(df)
```

```py
             A
idx1 idx2
X    h1    0.0
     h2    0.0
     h3    0.0
Z    h1    0.0
     h2    0.0
     h3    0.0
Y    h1    0.0
     h2    0.0
     h3    0.0
```

What's wrong with my second code? I am doing something really stupid, or is it some sort of expected behavior?

I tried on python 3.7.1 and 3.6.8, with pandas 0.23.4 in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tuples for set values in `MultiIndex` for avoid [chained indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy):

```
df.loc[('X','h1'),'A'] = 1.1
df.loc[('Y','h1'),'A'] = 2.2
df.loc[('Z','h1'),'A'] = 3.3

print(df)
             A
idx1 idx2     
X    h1    1.1
     h2    0.0
     h3    0.0
Z    h1    3.3
     h2    0.0
     h3    0.0
Y    h1    2.2
     h2    0.0
     h3    0.0
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Nevertheless I still don't understand why my version does not work. For example, if I use ```print(df.loc['Z','A']['h1'])``` after your code, it returns 3.3, as expected. Is it a copy, or a reference? Moreover, just changing the position of Y triggered the problem.

Comment: @Marcel - I think it depends - if not updated then you try change Series returned by `df.loc['Z','A']`, not column in `DataFrame`. I think better explanation is [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)